# Is there a word for the discarded part of a word that is truncated?

Tags: single-word-requests

My example is *Science Friday*, which can be shortened to *Sci Fri*

But what do you call the parts that aren't used – *ence day*

Comment: He told me there was a word for it, but elide. *[Joke. Couldn't resist. Sorry.]*

Comment: *Slow Clap into standing ovation*

Comment: Who bothers to  further name what would anyway be discarded ?

Comment: Because there's no room for waste anymore @Narasimham, there's just no room

Answer (score 6):

There is not a single word for that, the usual term is:

[*elided part/ portion*](https://www.google.it/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=%22elided+part%22&oq=%22elided+part%22&gs_l=hp.13..0i13i30l3j0i22i30j0i13i5i30l6.4139.9837.0.12357.14.14.0.0.0.0.349.2198.0j10j2j1.13.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..3.11.1735.0.WQRjg2nQDpI)

Comment: Hmmm. How do you know that there isn't such a word?

Comment: Can I call it not-truncated? xD

Comment: ha, perhaps truncatee

Answer (score 3):

Those would be "elisions".

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

> elision
>         n 1: omission of a sound between two words (usually a vowel and
>              the end of one word or the beginning of the next)
>         2: a deliberate act of omission; "with the exception of the
>            children, everyone was told the news" [syn: {exception},
>            {exclusion}, {elision}]

Comment: This is normally everything other than the first syllable – not a sound between words

Answer (score 0):

Two words that occur to me:

*remenant*

*remainder*